Cypher logic gates -AND/OR
I am simulating inputs which lead through logic gates.
I want to get active paths. The approach I have at the moment is to create a link for every active logic gate, to say which sim it is open in. But this isn't so neat.
Additionally, there is the problem of recursion, there may be more levels to this.
And, when Out1 & Out2 are active, only Out2 is reported.
Is there a way to recurse this type of logic?

Sample data
CREATE 
(s1:Sim {id:1}),(s2:Sim{id:2}),(s3:Sim{id:3}),(s4:Sim{id:4}),
(e1:Inputt {name: 'In1'}),(e2:Inputt {name: 'In2'}),(e3:Inputt{name: 'In3'}),(e4:Inputt{name: 'In4'}),(e5:Inputt{name: 'In5'}),(e6:Inputt{name: 'In6'}),
(x1:Outputt {name: 'Out1'}),(x2:Outputt {name: 'Out2'}),
(a1:GateAND),(a2:GateAND),(a3:GateAND),
(o1:GateOR),(o2:GateOR),
(e1)<-[:ACTIVE]-(s1),
(e3)<-[:ACTIVE]-(s1),
(e2)<-[:ACTIVE]-(s2),
(e4)<-[:ACTIVE]-(s2),
(e4)<-[:ACTIVE]-(s3),
(e5)<-[:ACTIVE]-(s3),
(e4)<-[:ACTIVE]-(s4),
(e5)<-[:ACTIVE]-(s4),
(e6)<-[:ACTIVE]-(s4),
(e1)-[:INTO]->(o1),
(e2)-[:INTO]->(o1),
(o1)-[:INTO]->(a1),
(e3)-[:INTO]->(a1),
(e4)-[:INTO]->(a2),
(e5)-[:INTO]->(a2),
(a1)-[:INTO]->(o2),
(a2)-[:INTO]->(o2),
(o2)-[:INTO]->(a3),
(e6)-[:INTO]->(a3),
(o2)-[:OUT]->(x1),
(a3)-[:OUT]->(x2)


Add:

1st level AND gate activations
1st level OR
2nd level AND (in another case, the second level could be OR
3rd level
4th level...

// First level OR gates only need one active input
MATCH (sim:Sim)-[:ACTIVE]->(inp:Inputt)-[:INTO]->(rule:GateOR)
WITH sim, rule, COUNT(inp) AS sfrEventCount
WHERE sfrEventCount >=1
MERGE (sim)-[:ACTIVE]->(rule)

// Add active to and gates
MATCH (inp:Inputt|GateOR)-[:INTO]->(gate:GateAND)
WITH ELEMENTID(gate) as gateId, COUNT(inp) AS inpCount
WITH apoc.map.fromPairs(COLLECT([gateId, inpCount])) AS gateIdCountMap
MATCH (sim:Sim)-[:ACTIVE]->(inp2:Inputt|GateOR)-[:INTO]->(rule)
WITH sim, rule, gateIdCountMap, COUNT(inp2) AS sinpCount
WHERE gateIdCountMap[ELEMENTID(rule)] = sinpCount
MERGE (sim) -[:ACTIVE]->(rule)

// Next level OR
MATCH (sim:Sim)-[:ACTIVE]->(inp:GateOR|GateAND)-[:INTO]->(rule:GateOR)
WITH sim, rule, COUNT(inp) AS sfrEventCount
WHERE sfrEventCount >=1
MERGE (sim)-[:ACTIVE]->(rule)

// DO the and again

// Outputs
MATCH (s:Sim)-[:ACTIVE]->(gate:GateAND|GateOR)-[:OUT]->(x:Outputt), (g2:GateAND|GateOR)<--(s2:Sim)
WHERE NOT EXISTS ((gate)-->(g2))
MERGE (s)-[:ACTIVE]->(x)


Results of interest. I would expect Out1 to be active in Sim 1 but somewhere Sim 4 took priority.
MATCH (s:Sim)-->(x:Outputt) return s, x



This query will find the legal paths:
MATCH path = (sim:Sim)-[:ACTIVE]->(input:Inputt)-[:INTO|OUT*0..]->(output:Outputt)
WHERE ALL(node IN nodes(path)[2..-1] 
  WHERE
    (node:GateAND AND ALL(incoming IN [(other)-[:INTO]->(node) | other] WHERE (sim)-[:ACTIVE|INTO*]->(incoming)))
    OR
    node:GateOR
)
RETURN sim, output, COLLECT(path) AS paths

But note that the query will be slow or even run out of memory if you have a lot of relevant data or long paths. If acceptable, you can ameliorate some of that by imposing a reasonable upper bound on the variable-length path patterns. For example:
MATCH path = (sim:Sim)-[:ACTIVE]->(input:Inputt)-[:INTO|OUT*0..8]->(output:Outputt)
WHERE ALL(node IN nodes(path)[2..-1] 
  WHERE
    (node:GateAND AND ALL(incoming IN [(other)-[:INTO]->(node) | other] WHERE (sim)-[:ACTIVE|INTO*..9]->(incoming)))
    OR
    node:GateOR
)
RETURN sim, output, COLLECT(path) AS paths

This is the output, given your sample data:
╒══════════════╤═════════════════════════╤════════════════════════════════╕
│sim           │output                   │paths                           │
╞══════════════╪═════════════════════════╪════════════════════════════════╡
│(:Sim {id: 1})│(:Outputt {name: "Out1"})│[(:Sim {id: 1})-[:ACTIVE]->(:Inp│
│              │                         │utt {name: "In3"})-[:INTO]->(:Ga│
│              │                         │teAND)-[:INTO]->(:GateOR)-[:OUT]│
│              │                         │->(:Outputt {name: "Out1"}), (:S│
│              │                         │im {id: 1})-[:ACTIVE]->(:Inputt │
│              │                         │{name: "In1"})-[:INTO]->(:GateOR│
│              │                         │)-[:INTO]->(:GateAND)-[:INTO]->(│
│              │                         │:GateOR)-[:OUT]->(:Outputt {name│
│              │                         │: "Out1"})]                     │
├──────────────┼─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│(:Sim {id: 3})│(:Outputt {name: "Out1"})│[(:Sim {id: 3})-[:ACTIVE]->(:Inp│
│              │                         │utt {name: "In4"})-[:INTO]->(:Ga│
│              │                         │teAND)-[:INTO]->(:GateOR)-[:OUT]│
│              │                         │->(:Outputt {name: "Out1"}), (:S│
│              │                         │im {id: 3})-[:ACTIVE]->(:Inputt │
│              │                         │{name: "In5"})-[:INTO]->(:GateAN│
│              │                         │D)-[:INTO]->(:GateOR)-[:OUT]->(:│
│              │                         │Outputt {name: "Out1"})]        │
├──────────────┼─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│(:Sim {id: 4})│(:Outputt {name: "Out1"})│[(:Sim {id: 4})-[:ACTIVE]->(:Inp│
│              │                         │utt {name: "In4"})-[:INTO]->(:Ga│
│              │                         │teAND)-[:INTO]->(:GateOR)-[:OUT]│
│              │                         │->(:Outputt {name: "Out1"}), (:S│
│              │                         │im {id: 4})-[:ACTIVE]->(:Inputt │
│              │                         │{name: "In5"})-[:INTO]->(:GateAN│
│              │                         │D)-[:INTO]->(:GateOR)-[:OUT]->(:│
│              │                         │Outputt {name: "Out1"})]        │
├──────────────┼─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│(:Sim {id: 4})│(:Outputt {name: "Out2"})│[(:Sim {id: 4})-[:ACTIVE]->(:Inp│
│              │                         │utt {name: "In6"})-[:INTO]->(:Ga│
│              │                         │teAND)-[:OUT]->(:Outputt {name: │
│              │                         │"Out2"}), (:Sim {id: 4})-[:ACTIV│
│              │                         │E]->(:Inputt {name: "In4"})-[:IN│
│              │                         │TO]->(:GateAND)-[:INTO]->(:GateO│
│              │                         │R)-[:INTO]->(:GateAND)-[:OUT]->(│
│              │                         │:Outputt {name: "Out2"}), (:Sim │
│              │                         │{id: 4})-[:ACTIVE]->(:Inputt {na│
│              │                         │me: "In5"})-[:INTO]->(:GateAND)-│
│              │                         │[:INTO]->(:GateOR)-[:INTO]->(:Ga│
│              │                         │teAND)-[:OUT]->(:Outputt {name: │
│              │                         │"Out2"})]                       │
└──────────────┴─────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────────┘


Wow this is great.
Now I just need to filter out the record sim 4, out1 -> because sim4 Out2 is active, and the gate that leads to Out1 also leads to the gate which leads to Out2, so it isn't the furthest output.
Path length isn't quite right for the filter since there are some short paths that can go more directly to the furthest right.

Your question merely stated that you want to get active paths. You should either update the question or create a new one. And please be very clear about your criteria for what to return from the query, as I do not understand your comment.

OK thanks.
This does work, but as you hinted, it is quite a heavy query.
